# ¿Como copiar los elementos de un vector tipo char en otro vector tipo char en C?

Tags: c

No sé cómo se copia un vector que tiene las 26 letras del abecedario en otro vector, me salen símbolos raros, mi código es:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define C 4

int main(){
    char uno[C]={"abc"}
    char dos[C]={}
    uno=dos;
    printf("%s",dos);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si ni siquiera te has molestado en poner un código minimamente en condiciones ... ¿ Que respuestas esperas ? La gente se esforzará en responderte lo mismo que tu te has esforzado al preguntar.

Comment: Busca `strcpy`. Y sigue aprendiendo mas sobre C, que con tener mas conocimiento entenderas porque te *salen simbolos raros*.

Answer (score 1):

Para copiar el contenido de un vector en otro vector se usa la funcion strcpy de la libreria `<string.h>`, debes procurar que la longitud del vector de destino sea igual o mayor a la longitud del vector origen, de lo contrario, va a ocurrir un desbordamiento del vector.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char origen[11] = "hola mundo";
    char destino[11];
    
    strcpy(destino,origen);
    
    printf("Vector copiado: %s",destino);
    
    return 0;
}
```